# GLib: how to quit main loop automatically started by g_initable_new()?

Tags: c, glib, dbus

My excuses for the newbie question:

I used gdbus-codegen to generate a C-code D-Bus client proxy, running on a Yocto Linux embedded system. The generated code calls g_initable_new(), returning a GInitable *.

At this point, two new threads appear: from the stack trace, I see that one calls g_main_loop_run(), and the other g_main_context_iteration(). So I gather that under the hood, g_initable_new() started a new main loop. OK so far.

When I'm done, I call g_object_unref() on my GInitable *. That works too, but the two threads are still running. How do I quit that loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the two threads? They should have a name in the process viewer. GDBus creates several worker threads which persist for the lifetime of the process, to handle D-Bus traffic. There is no way to stop them. These may be those threads.

Comment: @Philip: The one calling g_main_loop_run() is called "gdbus", and the one calling g_main_context_iteration() is "gmain".

Comment: I figured "gmain" is probably running the default main context, so I tried to do a g_main_context_default() (which indeed returned non-null) and a g_main_context_unref() on it. As one might expect, that didn't do anything.

I'd like to stop these threads, because I do a fork() afterwards, and I'd rather not have my child process inheriting some useless threads.
I'm currently rooting around in the GLib/GIo source code; nothing yet.

Comment: Your comment does give me another idea of how to solve my problem: spawn another process to run the gdbus code, so that the gdbus worker thread does not "pollute" my main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other @Philip confirmed, GDBus creates worker threads that can apparently not be stopped. Boo hiss.

My initial concern was that I didn't want my child process to inherit some useless - and potentially harmful - threads. But actually, fork() takes care of that, as noted in the manpage: "The child process is created with a single thread — the one that called fork()." So this concern is unfounded.

But I discovered another good reason to spawn the D-Bus code: I have a setuid program, and as soon as I call setreuid() to reduce the privileges of my process, the gdbus worker threads fail (which makes sense).

So that appears to be my answer: you can't quit the GDBus worker threads, and if that's not OK, isolate the GDBus stuff in a process of its own.